# Calling methods from the constructor

Tags: java, function, methods, constructor

I wrote the below code, and as you see, in the constructor I call some methods to perform certain operations. And now what I am inquiring about is, whether it is a good practice to call those methods from the constructor OR declare those methods as public and instantiate an object from the class info, and let the object call those methods? What is the good practice for that?

## Code:

```
class Info {
public RoadInfo(String cityName, double lat, double lng) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.cityname = cityName;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;

    this.path = "c:"+File.separatorChar+this.cityname+".xml";

    System.out.println(path);
    
    this.initXPath();
    this.method1()
    this.method2()
    ..

    this.expr = "//node[@lat='"+this.lat+"'"+"]/following-sibling::tag[1]/@v";
    this.xPath.compile(this.expr);
    String s = (String) this.xPath.evaluate(this.expr, this.document, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd expect the constructor to provide me with an object I can start working with straight away, so I wouldn't want to have to call methods to initialise things after the constructor every time I instantiate an instance of that class. Calling methods from the constructor seems fine to me.

Comment: (In a comment because I'm not informed enough to state this for sure): In my opinion, *no*. Your constructor is just for capturing state passed to it. If you find yourself needing to perform logic on state passed to your constructor, you need another level of indirection.

Comment: Keep the constructor simple. Constructor should have the code, which is  related to initialization of object. I prefer to to move non-initialization part of the code to outside of constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR** In my opinion, using methods inside of a constructor is a sign of bad design. If you aren't looking for design advice, then the answer "no there's nothing wrong with it, technically speaking, as long as you avoid calling non-final methods" should do you fine. If you ARE looking for design advice, see below.

I think your example code is not good practice at all. In my opinion, a constructor should only receive values which is relevant to it and should not need to perform any other initialization on those values. There's no way for you to test that your constructor 'works' with all of those little extra steps - all you can do is construct the object and hope that everything ends up in the correct state. Further, your constructor ends up with more than one reason to change, which violates the SRP.

```
class Info {
public RoadInfo(String cityName, double lat, double lng) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.cityname = cityName;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;

    this.path = "c:"+File.separatorChar+this.cityname+".xml";

    System.out.println(path);

    this.initXPath();
    this.method1()
    this.method2()
    ..

    this.expr = "//node[@lat='"+this.lat+"'"+"]/following-sibling::tag[1]/@v";
    this.xPath.compile(this.expr);
    String s = (String) this.xPath.evaluate(this.expr, this.document, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

So, for example, this *constructor* is loading a file, parsing it in XPath.. if I ever want to create a `RoadInfo` object, I can now only do it by loading files and having to worry about exceptions being thrown. This class also now becomes hilariously difficult to unit test because now you can't test the `this.initXPath()` method in isolation, for example - if `this.initXPath()`, `this.method1()` or `this.method2()` have any failures, then every one of your test cases will fail. Bad!

I would prefer it to look something more like this:

```
class RoadInfoFactory {
  public RoadInfo getRoadInfo(String cityName, double lat, double lng) {
    String path = this.buildPathForCityName(cityName);
    String expression = this.buildExpressionForLatitute(lat);
    XPath xpath = this.initializeXPath();
    XDocument document = ...;

    String s =  (String) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.STRING);
    // Or whatever you do with it..
    return new RoadInfo(s);
  }
}
```

Never mind the fact that you have at least 5 responsibilities here.

- Build OS-neutral path
- Build XPath expression for latitude/longitude
- Create XPath doocument
- Retrieve `s` - whatever that is
- Create new `RoadInfo` instance

Each of these responsibilities (Except the last) should be separated into their own classes (IMO), and have `RoadInfoFactory` orchestrate them all together.

Comment: I would say separating the building of the XPath expression into a separate class is probably a bit of an overkill, but a separate method definitely.

Comment: I would rather build an XPath expression programmatically than by hand, which is why I suggest separating it.

Comment: @biziclop sorry for msunderstanding but do u mean that it is good to separate building the XPath expression into classes  or not??

Comment: @maik I think he is stating that having a separate class for building the XPath expression is overkill.

Comment: @DanPantry Yes, but I don't mean it as "don't ever do it", just that in this case it maybe is a little bit over the top. If you have multiple XPaths or a more complicated XPath, that's a different story.

Comment: @biziclop that's my point as well. I would have one class for the purpose of building *all* XPaths via a fluent interface, not a class for building *each individual XPath*.

Comment: @DanPantry I agree. Sorry, for confusing things. :)

Comment: @DanPantry as you satated in ur comment " I would have one class for the purpose of building all XPaths via a fluent interface, not a class for building each individual XPath"..would u please give me an example of using the interface to build the xpath..it would be usefull and beneficial to me as i have not used user-defined interfaces in development and i am so eager to know howw that can be done..

Comment: @maik I don't know any to hand, it was just an example of the approach *I* would personally take.

Comment: @DanPantry i think the RoadInfoFactory class you coded in ur answer could be static as well, isnt??

Comment: @user2121 no. I only provided a basic example; that factory has dependencies. Unless you want to use the service locator pattern (don't), you would want it to be non-static.

Comment: @DanPantry you stated "There's no way for you to test that your constructor 'works' with all of those little extra steps"..what if i placed some if-else conditions inside each method "i am calling frim inside the constructor" to trace wherefrom the failure might come? would it be a solution

Comment: Yeah but that would be a hell of a lot of extra work.. and very brittle.. so I don't know why you would do that. You'd be making more work for yourself doing that.

Comment: @DanPantry can u please let me know , why you returned "new RoadInfo(s);" and not "return s;"?? and "s" is just a string

Comment: @maik Because I have no idea what `s` is. All I know is that in your original code, `RoadInfo` required it/stored it. (This is why you name your variables descriptively).

Comment: @DanPantry i think before i call the methods u used in the RoadInfoFactory class i ahve to do the following assignement: this.cityname = cityName;
  this.lat = lat;
  this.lng = lng;   right?

Comment: Erm, no. those are meant to be passed in from the caller.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the constructor is to establish the class invariants, that is, to bring the newly created object into a state that then allows clients to use them. In general, it is bad practice for an object to be relying on extra initialisation **after** it's constructed. What you want to avoid is to write such things into the documentation as:

> ...after creating an instance of class `X`, remember to ALWAYS call
>   `initX()`, or bad things will happen!

Though in certain cases it's difficult to avoid it and the constructor can become quite messy. For example loading external files in a constructor is problematic.

In these cases there are two things you can do:

1. Rewrite your constructor so it requires the contents of the file instead of the name. Let the caller do the loading. The main difference is that you require the caller to do something **before** the object is created, and you can express it with the signature of your constructor: `public RoadInfo(String cityName, Document cityDatabase, double lat, double lng) {...}` Of course you can go even further and require the value of `s` straight away and let the caller do the XPath search. Note that all these steps move the class towards having a single responsibility, which is considered a good thing.
2. But now you require the caller to perform many steps before they can build your `RoadInfo`. This is where you can use factories, which perform this extra initialisation too and return fully built `RoadInfo` objects.

---

The most important thing though is that **the constructor must not call any method of the object under construction that can be overridden**. Calling private methods is fine, calling public methods on `this` is not a good idea unless the methods or the class itself is marked as `final`.

If you call such a method, there's always a chance that the class overriding the method does something that breaks your functionality, like exposing `this` to the outside world before the construction is completed. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public Foo(String param) {
       if (this.processParam(param) == null)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Can't process param.");
    }

    protected abstract processParam(String param);
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar(String param) {super(param);}

    protected processParam(String param) {
        SomeOtherClass.registerListener(this); // Things go horribly wrong here
        return null; 
    }
}
```

If you now call `new Bar("x")`, the constructor of `Foo` will throw an exception because it considers the parameter invalid. But `Bar.processParam()` leaked a reference of `this` to `SomeOtherClass`, potentially allowing `SomeOtherClass` to use the `Bar` instance that shouldn't even exist.

Comment: would u please clarify the following "calling public methods is not a good idea unless the methods or the class itself is marked as final"..why do i need to mark the class a sfinal when i want to call public method

Comment: @user2121 I meant public methods of the object being constructed, You can of course call public methods of other objects freely. I'll try to clarify it somehow.

Comment: @user2121 because if you call a non-final method in a constructor in a class that can be extended then someone might override that method in a subclass. Lets say the overriden method depends on some state in the object, well, if you set that state *after* you call your non-final method, then the non-final method will see the state as being incorrect. You may also accidentally leak the object whilst its not fully constructed to other parts of the application. It's a large can of worms that is easily avoided by just setting methods to `final`.

Comment: @biziclop kindly, would u please clarify..u stated 2If you now call new Bar("x"), the constructor of Foo will throw an exception".. and i think if i created new Bar("x"), this wouldnt be a problem because the constructor of Foo accepts a String parameter!!

Comment: @maik read the code again... `Foo` would throw an exception if `processParam` returns null, which is overridden in a derived class which leaks the `this` pointer = really, really bad.

Answer (score 4):

More typically, classes requiring heavy initialization would be provided to the client via a factory method. Constructors are often too restrictive—a random example being the inability to surround the `super` or `this` opening call with `try-catch`.

If you provide a public factory method, you can make the constructor private. The constructor can only do the easy work like assigning final fields, and the factory takes over. In the long run this is a more future-proof design. Many public libraries had to break their earlier API to introduce factories that allow their code to grow.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good practice to call some methods from the constructor?

Sadly the only good answer to this is *It depends on the object*.

If the object is intended to **hold information** then the answer must be *probably not, try to avoid it* because an object should really only [do one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If, however, the object is there to **perform a function** then by all means make sure that it is ready to perform that function by calling methods etc. If, for example it is a database connection then you might wish to connect to the database at construct time, or at least register itself in a connection pool.

It is, however, good practice to postpone any potentially slow stuff you *can* postpone until you need it. In my example of the database you may wish to postpone the actual connection to the database but you would certainly register the connection in the connection pool.

Sadly - the answer to the opposite question:

> Is it a **bad** practice to call some methods from the constructor?

Is also *It depends on the object* for similar reasons.

Comment: As die hard as I am in my answer, this bit of this answer cannot be understated enough: "it depends". There's no hard and fast rules in programming, and sometimes you need to write bad/inelegant/ugly code to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good practice, just bad practice that you should not do.

When you call a method within a constructor, some dangerous here are:

1) the method can be overwritten, and its subclass implement break your class's constraint protected by constructor, the implement is out of your control.

```
class T {
    int v;

    T() {
        v = getValue();
    }

    int getValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Sub extends T {
    @Override
    int getValue() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

here T's v suppose to be 1 when you call `new T()`, but when you create a `new Sub()`, 'v' will be set to -1, which may break T's constraint, and this happens unconsciously.

2) the half-constructed object leaked, while it's status may be illegal.

```
class T {
    int a, b;

    T(C c) {
        // status of "this" is illegal now, but visible to c
        c.calc(this);
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
    }
}

class C {
    int calc(T t) {
        return t.a / t.b;
    }
}
```

3) something more I don't know...

if you can prevent all of them, you can do what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer. would u please clarify how the the method could be overwritten as u stated in point number 1. also i dont understabd what do u mean by half-constructed and leaked object??!

Comment: @maik if you don't make the class final I could subclass your class and then overwrite the method you're calling

Answer (score 0):

- (Try to keep exceptions not thrown. So the constructor can nicely initialize a field.)
- Do not call overridable methods in the constructor.

***About the pitfalls of an overridable method call in a constructor:***

The evaluation of a (child) constructor is:

- "Zero" all fields (`0, null, 0.0, false`)
- Call the super constructor (implicit if not in code)
- Call all field initializations (field declarations with = ...)
- Do rest of constructor code

So:

```
class A {
    A() { f(); }
    protected void f() { }
}

class B implements A {
    String a;
    String b = null;
    String c = "c";

    B() {
        //[ a = null, b = null, c = null; ]
        //[ super();
        //    B.f();
        //]
        //[ b = null; ]
        //[ c = "c"; ]

        // "nullA" - null - "c"
        System.out.printf("end %s - %s - %s%n", a, b, c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void f() {
        System.out.printf("enter f : %s - %s - %s%n", a, b, c);
        // null - null - null
        a += "A";
        b += "B";
        c += "C";
        // "nullA" - "nullB" - "nullC"
        System.out.printf("leave f : %s - %s - %s%n", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

That behavior is quite muddying the waters, and here doing assignments that are immediately overwritten by field initializations.

A normal call one often sees in constructors is a setter, that maybe has some normalization code. Make that setter `public final void setX(X x);`.